# Rails Friendly ID Custom Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm trying to get my routes to work like this:

```
/articles/<category slug>/<article slug>
```

I'm using:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.1"
```

I have a category that has many articles

**the url structure now is:**

/categories/

/articles/

**because my routes.rb file looks like this:**

```
resources :categories
resources :articles
```

**my article.rb file:**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    extend FriendlyId 
    friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :globalize]

    def slug_candidates
      [
        :name
      ]
    end
end
```

**here's my category.rb:**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :articles

        extend FriendlyId 
        friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :globalize]

        # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
        # increasing order of specificity.
        def slug_candidates
          [
            :name
          ]
        end
end
```

If I do a nested route like this:

```
resources :categories do
   resources :articles
end
```

**then the structure becomes** `/categories/<category slug>/articles/<article slug>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this does exactly what I want. It's expanded off of mbillard's answer:

```
  get "/articles", to: "articles#index"
  resources :categories, path: 'articles' do
    resources :articles, path: '', only: [:show]
  end
  resources :articles, only: [:index, :new, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
resources :categories do
  get ':article_slug', to: 'articles#show' # => /categories/:category_id/:article_slug
end
```

or even:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :articles, path: ''
end
```

Be careful though, because this will catch anything after `/categories/:category_slug/.../`. I don't know what's the behavior with the regular routes like `new` and `edit` though.